# Pytest - Extract data generated by test run to a file/ fixture in conftest?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pytest

I am using Pytest framwork for testing a web applications.
While the tests run, it generates data and store them into variables.

Example:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixture("test_setup")
class TestArticleCreation:
    def test_new_article_creation(self):
        art = ArticleCreation(self.driver)
        art.create_new_article()
        article_id = art.get_new_article_id()
        assert art.verify_article_created_in_db(article_id)
```

I want to extract article_id, and store it so i can delete it later, but i do not want the ids extraction process to be part of the test itself, even tho i cannot think/ know of any other way to do that beside adding a function to the test, that will write article_id value to a file. Does Pytest provide solution for this?

I use conftest.py to build configurations, and the project is built with POM design pattern if thats help somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a bit more information about the code you want to test, the framework you use for web development and what you did try so far, so that we can [reproduce your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice solution, not sure its the best..
It is possible to extract variables from module level,

So above the TestClass i declared a new variable, type(list).
When a test generating an id, i can add it to the list above,

```
# tests/test_sanity.py
article_ids = []

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("test_setup")  # USE "test_setup"   FIXTURE with scope=class
class TestSanity:

    def test_global_var(self):
        art_id = '12321342154'
        global article_ids  # Declare the in module var as global
        article_ids.append(art_id)  # Add id generated in test run
        assert article_id == '12321342154'


# conftest.py

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper  # Add hook wrapper to tests teardown
def pytest_runtest_teardown(item):
    yield
    print(item.module.article_ids)  # By this access the global var decalred in our test module
```

Only problem i face right now is the hook wrapper called each test and not per session.

Edit:

Found another way to do so:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def ids():
    ids = []
    yield ids
    print(ids)


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def api_setup(request, ids):
    request.cls.ids = ids

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("api_setup") 
class TestSome:
    def test_something(self):
        global article_ids
        art_id = '123'
        self.ids.append(art_id)
        assert art_id == '123'
```

This way it does add each id generated to the list, but does not call conftest.py at the end of each test